# google maps api can't add marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have silly problem, I can't add marker with GoogleMaps API. I almost copied script from examples and it doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    initialize();
});


function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom : 6,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
    });
}

function placeMarker(position, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : position,
        map : map
    });
    map.panTo(position);
}
</script>
```

is something wrong with this code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code, it works fine for me.

Comment: strange :O, in my browser marker doesn't appear

Comment: Works for me too.  Did you click on the map?

Comment: yes, location changes, there's move but marker just doesn't appear

Comment: ok, there is no problem, i'm using template and haven't noticed that there was linked other google maps api but without key, so must have been conflict